# calling function with web3 is not working correctly?

Tags: solidity, web3js, react

I have a problem like this. I have built a smart contract and have deployed it to the infura network. All other functions are working correctly when interacting with web3 but when I calling one function it gives me an error by saying that

```
__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__ethereum_factory__.a.methods.getDeployedContract is not a function
```

This is how I am interacting with it.

```
import React,{ Component } from 'react';
import { Button, Form, Grid, Message } from 'semantic-ui-react';

import web3 from '../ethereum/web3';
import factory from '../ethereum/factory';
import Driver from '../ethereum/driver';

import Layout from './Layout';
import Header from './Header';


export default class Dofine extends Component {
  state ={
    offenceId: 0,
    location: '',
    driver: 0
  };

  handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
        offenceId: event.target.value
    });
}


  onSubmit = async (event) =>{
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ loading: true, errorMessage: ''});
    console.log(this.state.driver);
    console.log(this.state.offenceId);

    try{
      const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
      const driverCd = await factory.methods.getDeployedContract(this.state.driver).call();

      // const driver = Driver(driverCd);
      // const user = driver.methods.getDetails().call();
      console.log(driverCd);

      // await factory.methods.doFine(this.state.offenceId,this.state.location,this.state.driver)
      //   .send({
      //       gas:"3000000",
      //       from: accounts[0]
      //   });

    }catch(err){
      this.setState({ errorMessage: err.message})
    }

    this.setState({ loading: false});
  }
    render(){
        return(
          <div>
          <Header></Header>
          <Layout>
            <Grid>
              <Grid.Row>
              <Grid.Column width={5}></Grid.Column>
              <Grid.Column width={6}>
           <Form onSubmit={this.onSubmit} error={!!this.state.errorMessage}>
             <center><h3>Do Fine</h3></center>
              <Form.Field>
                <label>Offence</label>
                <select value={this.state.offenceId} onChange ={this.handleChange}>
                    <option value="1">Overtake on the Zebra Crossing</option>
                    <option value="2">Overtake On the Left</option>
                    {/* <option value="coconut">Coconut</option>
                    <option value="mango">Mango</option> */}
                </select>
              </Form.Field>
              <Form.Field>
                <label>Location</label>
                <input placeholder='Colombo'  value={this.state.location}
                        onChange ={event => this.setState({ location: event.target.value})}/>
              </Form.Field>
              <Form.Field>
                <label>Address Of the Driver</label>
                <input placeholder='0xdCF0A9F8413B1229E426DF2dE76873150d8B1c9B'  value={this.state.driver}
                        onChange ={event => this.setState({ driver: event.target.value})}/>
              </Form.Field>
              <Message error header="Oops!" content={this.state.errorMessage} />
                    <Button loading={this.state.loading} color="green" basic>Do Fine</Button> <Button  loading={this.state.loading} color="red" basic >Clear</Button>
            </Form>
            </Grid.Column>
            </Grid.Row>
            </Grid>
            </Layout>

            </div>

        )
    }
}
```

This is my factory contract.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract Driverfactory{

    struct Driver {
        address contractd;
        address account;
    }

    address[] private deployedDriverContracts;

    mapping(address=>Driver) public drivers;

    function createDriver(string lisenceId,string firstName,string lastName,string vehicle,string vehicleType) public{
        require(msg.sender!=drivers[msg.sender].account);
        address newDriver = new DriverProfile(lisenceId,firstName,lastName,vehicle,vehicleType,msg.sender);
        deployedDriverContracts.push(newDriver);
        Driver  memory newDriver1 = Driver({
            contractd:newDriver,
            account:msg.sender
        });
        drivers[msg.sender] = newDriver1;
    }

    function getDeployedDriverContracts() public view returns(address[]){
        return deployedDriverContracts; 
    }

    function checkDriver(address driver) public view returns(bool){
        if(driver==drivers[driver].account){
            return true;
        }

        else{
            return false;
        }

    }

    function driverContract(address driver) public view returns(address){
        address dc_adrs =drivers[driver].contractd;
        return dc_adrs;
    }



}



contract DriverProfile{
    struct Driver{
        string lisenceId;
        string firstName ;
        string lastName; 
        address account;
        string vehicle;
        string vehicleType;
        uint totalOffenceAmount;
        uint offenceCount;
        uint pendingPayments;
        mapping(uint=>Fine)  fines;
    }

    Driver public driver;

    constructor(string lisenceId,string firstName,string lastName,string vehicle,string vehicleType,address owner) public{
        driver = Driver({
            lisenceId:lisenceId,
            lastName:lastName,
            firstName:firstName,
            account:owner,
            vehicle:vehicle,
            vehicleType:vehicleType,
            totalOffenceAmount:0,
            offenceCount:0,
            pendingPayments:0
        });
    }





}
```

And That is work fine when I interact with the deployed contract through Remix editor. Can someone help me to solve this problem? Thank You.

Comment: It is quite difficult to understand a reason, based on the description. Make sure that you compiled last version of contract and you execute functions of latest version of contract, which should match with your code. If it will not work, pls share a factory smart contract.

Comment: check factory and web3, you might be exporting a incorrect object

Comment: @KashishKhullar But all other methods in that contract is working

Comment: @Aquila yes when I intract with that contract using at Address option in Remix all function  are working as expected

Comment: @Aquila I have updated the question with my factory contract.

Comment: Try redeploying the contract

Comment: @dwp factory contract doesn't have `getDeployedContract` function, means the issue related to '../ethereum/factory' implementation. It can by simple mistake in execution of function, because `factory` which imported in a code is not instance of contract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function in your contract is

> getDeployedDriverContracts()

And in the error you see it is

> ethereum_factory__.a.methods.getDeployedContract is not a function

The incorrect spelling must be causing the error.